# How do I display a same div for a number times that user input in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dom, frontend

I have POS system with cheque payments. when the cashier input the number of cheque according to the input the cheque detail form should generated.

Eg : if he enter Number 5, the same form should be display five times How can i do this with jquery.

I have attached up to what i have done so far !!
Thanks in Advance

This is the user input

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberOfChq" >
<a id="come" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
```

This is the div to be repeated
        `<div id="chk_list" hidden></div>`

This is the jquery i tried its displaying only once, i want to diplay as many user input

```
        $("#come").click(function(){
           var chqNumebr = $("#numberOfChq").val();
           var i;
           for (i= 1; i <= chqNumebr; i++ ){
          var chqSh = $("#chk_list").slideDown("slow");
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below.

First we need something to add the new divs into, so I created `<div id="output"></div>` for that.

After pressing submit, you'll see the new divs get added according the number the user entered. But we have to make sure that we empty `#output` every time the function runs otherwise the newly created divs would just keep adding onto the existing ones.

Secondly, if we are going to have multiple instances of `#chk_list` then it shouldn't have an ID as all ID's should be unique. Instead, we'll use a class.

```js
$("#come").on('click', function() {
  var chqNumebr = $("#numberOfChq").val();
  //empty divs that are currently inside of #output
  $('#output').empty();
  for (var i = 0; i < chqNumebr; i++) {
    $('#output').append('<div class="chk_list"></div>')
  }
});
```

```css
.chk_list {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="numberOfChq">
<a id="come" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I have a form inside the ```<div class="chk_list"></div>``` so should I copy the whole form to append?

Comment: and also how can i remove all divs in on click